# Get user id of newly registered user in Userpro plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using wordpress Userspro plugin for creating new user.I want to get user id of newly created user.I am using following code but i receive javascript error in browser alertbox

```
function getUserId( $user_id )
{        
die('ends');
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'getUserId');
```

Any help would be appreciable.Thanks

Comment: Do you want  $user_id?

Comment: yes @hamid i want $user_id.

Comment: you can use  `return $user_id;` instead of die('ends');

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.Actually i was checking that this function works on new user registeration.So thats why i use die function.But die function is throwing error.I update this $user_id in wp_options table and find that this function really works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and get $user_id.

```
function getUserId( $user_id )
{        
    return $user_id;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'getUserId');
```